# ALSA only detecting HDMI sound card, not analog

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I'm dual booting Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows, and I keep running into a problem where I get no sound. At first, I managed to "fix" it by running `rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k` (or some variation of) and rebooting, but every time I reboot after that it would come back, requiring me to try and fix again. This time, I haven't been able to fix it. I checked `alsamixer`, and apparently it's only detecting the HDMI sound card, which isn't helpful. The output of `aplay -l` is

```
    **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

It might be worth noting that whenever the sound fails in Ubuntu, I get an issue in Windows where it thinks there is "no audio output device" installed. Any ideas? I'm not too familiar with Ubuntu any help or clarification is much appreciated.